# aws lambda with S3 trigger is not firing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function, which I deployed with a container image.
The function itself is super simple, and it basically prints something stupid.
When I'm testing it using the "test" tab in the console I get "Execution succeeded":
[image]

But when I add a s3 trigger - nothing happens when I upload a file to the S3 bucket!

This is the function overview:

[image]

This is the Execution role:
[image]

And this is the relevant policy in the "simple role" role, which should grant access to S3:

[image]

Here is the relevant bucket, when I upload file to it nothing happens in the Lambda!

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the function *did* execute, but you cannot see its output.

The **IAM policy** associated with the **AWS Lambda function** should have, at minimum, the [`AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html), which grants permission to upload logs to CloudWatch. This way, you can debug the function.

Without those permissions, the only indication that the function executed would be the 'Invocations' graph in the Monitoring section of the function.

Comment: Thank you man! Sorry for the basic question, but the portal is so not intuitive (for me) - what is the easiest way to grant the BasicExecution role to a lambda function?

Comment: Go to the IAM Console and select the IAM Role that the AWS Lambda function is using. In the **Permissions policies** section, select **Add Permissions** and **Attach Policies**. Then add the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`.